# C# ADOX adDBDate type column not working

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, adox

I want to create programatically a database and I create into that database a table.(.MDB Access database)
I create the database and the table using the ADOX integrated functions, "Catalog" for the database and "Table" for the table inside the db.

```
Table tabelreceptii = new Table();
tabelreceptii.Name = "Receptii";
tabelreceptii.Columns.Append("NumarReceptie", DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 10);
tabelreceptii.Columns.Append("DataReceptie", DataTypeEnum.adDBDate);
cat2.Tables.Append(tabelreceptii);
```

When I try to run the app, occurs the "Type is invalid." error, with the error code "ErrorCode=-2147217859".

I realized that the problem is in this part of code:

```
tabelreceptii.Columns.Append("DataReceptie", DataTypeEnum.adDBDate);
```

The adDBDate type seems not working in my case, and I really need  a DATE column in my table. Any solutions?

Comment: See the difference between adDBDate and adDate in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and select the appropriate type to the data you have. Also check if the value is invalid in the source.

Comment: If it's .mdb access, why tagging both MySql and Sql-Server, that are irrelevant, instead of ms-access?

Comment: @Emmad Kareem: Thank's a lot! I've changed the adDBDate in adDate and it works. :)

Comment: @EmmadKareem: Please consider writing your suggested solution as an answer, so that the OP can accept it and other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Valid suggestion. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between adDBDate and adDate types as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Choose the type that represents the data that you have or expect to use.

- adDate:  Indicates a date value (DBTYPE_DATE). A date is stored as a double, the whole part of which is the number of days since December 30, 1899, and the fractional part of which is the fraction of a day.
- adDBDate: - Indicates a date value (yyyymmdd) (DBTYPE_DBDATE).

Comment: You should thicken it up a bit to make it a proper answer. Add some text explanations and some quotes from the documentation, you'll get my upvote and probably some other upvotes as well.

Comment: @Zohar Peled, Advice appreciated, will do when I get a chance.